# Why C# Regex.Match doesn't accept type Regex as second argument?

Tags: c#, regex

I wonder why does the static method `Match` in `Regex.Match` receive two obligatory parameters and more optionals and the second parameter doesn't accept a true `Regex`.

The method specification in Microsoft MSDN is:

```
public string Replace(
    string input,
    string replacement
)
```

In Visual Studio it is different:

[image: Visual Studio]

The second parameter is made to "support" Regex as says **The Regular expression pattern to match**

Then, the following code is invalid:

```
  string str = "my {value}";
  Regex pattern = new Regex(@"\{[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\}");
  int matches = Regex.Match(str, pattern);
```

But when:

```
string pattern = @"\{[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\}";
```

It is valid.

Am I getting crazy or this is really a issue?

I know, it says that receives "string", but wouldn't be correctly also support type `Regex`?

Comment: If you have an instance of a Regex, why would you want to pass that instance to a static method on Regex?

Comment: Why should it? "I don't like `pattern.Match(str)`" is not good enough reason to add such override...

Comment: I want to keep an answer about that for reference. Because VisualStudio documentation about C# in the more recent version is different from Microsofts MSDN documentation. For more people who wonder this.

Comment: Are you asking why you cannot pass a Regex to a method that takes a String argument? You cannot do that because types matter in C# and .NET has no meaningful way of implicitly converting a Regex to a String.

Comment: I think that using a type string to store a Regex is a big workaround from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is entirely clear what you are asking, but I will have a go at answering part of your question anyway.

> The second parameter is made to "support" Regex as says The Regular expression pattern to match

If I understand you correctly, you are asking why you cannot pass a `Regex` when the description of the parameter says that it takes a regular expression.

**Regex vs. regular expressions**

It is important here to distinguish between the .NET type `Regex` and the concept of a regular expression: `Regex` is a .NET type just like `Color`, `String`, `StringBuilder` etc. It is designed to represent a regular expression and it has convenient methods for working with regular expressions. However, it isn't in itself a regular expression.

On the other hand, the string of characters "abc.*" is [a regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), not just in C# but in a general sense. Not all strings are valid regular expressions, but some strings are regular expressions and can be used to describe a universe of matching strings.

**Method signatures**

What the documentation above states is that the method takes a parameter, `pattern`, of type `string`. The comments associated with the parameter state that the pattern must represent a valid regular expression. Thus, it must conform to the rules describing regular expressions in .NET and cannot, say, contain "?[---]<>", because that string does not represent a regular expression (I assume, I haven't tested it).

To sum up: you cannot pass an instance of the type `Regex` for the pattern parameter, because *the method is not asking for an instance of `Regex`, it is very explicitly asking for a regular expression expressed as a string*.

**Note:** The documentation matching the method overload you are looking at can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2heewz(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `pattern` *is* a Regex.

You probably want:

```
var matches = pattern.Match(str);
```

the reason the static version exists, is that it adds a quick way to match a regular expression in a one-off, disposable way.

Since Regex's internal state machines can take time to compile - the instance version exists so you can create an instance - and only have to compile it one time - for example, if you were running it many times within a loop, you could see a considerable performance improvement.

Comment: I know. But I wonder why doesn't Microsoft synchronize both MSDN and VS documentation to the correct.

Comment: @TonyCamargo Are you sure you are looking at the documentation corresponding to your version of .NET? Could you provide a link to the MSDN docs and state what version of .NET you are using?

Comment: I'm using .NET 4.5. The MSDN documentation about Regex.Match is 4.5. They are the same.

Comment: @TonyCamargo - where are links? It is very hard to understand what you actually asking based on just your claim "Microsoft doesn't synchronize both MSDN and VS documentation".

Answer (score 0):

MSDN documentation for [Regex.Mathc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2heewz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says:

```
pattern
   Type: System.String
   The regular expression pattern to match.
```

"The regular expression pattern to match." means "String representation of regular expression to match, with possible extensions to usual regular expression syntax supported by .Net runtime". It looks like you read the sentence as "... also accepting `RegEx` variable named `pattern`".

Note that [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is normal computer science / language theory term and does not have to match any particular class in any framework.

While it may be useful to add "String with the regular expression", it does not feel very useful because type is shown immediately before the sentence.